# Duda al definir vector en Pila

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

imaginemos que tenemos la típica clase Pila:

```
template <typename  tElemento> 
class Pila
{
  public:
.........
  private:
    tElemento *elementos;              //Vector de elementos
    int Lmax;                          //Tamaño del vector
    int tope_;                         //Posicion del tope
};
```

No logro entender cómo está definiendo exactamente el vector para una pila de por ejemplo números (1,2,3...), es decir:

```
tElemento *elementos;
```

o lo que es igual:

```
int *elementos;
```

Si en teoría cuando definimos un vector, por ejemplo, como si fuera una pila, definimos el vector de la siguiente forma:

```
int vector[Lmax] = {"1", "2", "3"...}; //Siendo Lmax constante definida
```

ó

```
int vector2[] = {1,2,3,4,10,9,80,70,19};
```

¿Porqué en realidad para definir dentro de la clase define el vector como un simple puntero?
Entiendo que un puntero contiene la dirección de memoria que apunta al primer elemento de un vector, pero no define en sí el vector? Es lo que no logro entender.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

#### Contexto.

Normalmente los contenedores de datos no guardan el dato en crudo si no una estructura que envuelve el dato y describe la manera en que un dato se relaciona con el siguiente; esta estructura suele ser llamada *Nodo* en muchas implementaciones.

Por ejemplo, si tienes Nodos que se relacionan sólo con el siguiente Nodo daría lugar a una [lista simplemente enlazada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_enlazada#Listas_simples_enlazadas), si en lugar de eso se enlazase con el siguiente y anterior Nodo sería una [lista doblemente enlazada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_enlazada#Listas_doblemente_enlazadas), si tienes como relación mayor-menor podrías tener un Nodo de [árbol binario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rbol_binario) o si el Nodo puede contener múltiples hijos tal vez sea un [árbol hash](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rbol_de_Merkle).

#### Pilas.

Las [Pilas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pila_(inform%C3%A1tica)) "*apilan*" datos uno sobre otro y todas las operaciones se realizan sobre el elemento superior; ese tipo de comportamiento es fácil de implementar con una lista simplemente enlazada, ya que puedes apuntar al Nodo superior y tendrás datos mientras los Nodos tengan otros Nodos "*debajo*".

Tu clase `Pila` carece de Nodos, así que no tiene manera de describir cómo un dato se relaciona con el siguiente, y por eso (como ya has observado) no hay manera de gestionar de manera fácil la pila. Pero eso no significa que sea imposible...

#### Formaciones<sup>1</sup>.

> ¿Porqué en realidad para definir dentro de la clase define el vector como un simple puntero?

Las formaciones de C++ son un espacio contiguo en memoria que almacenan un tipo de dato, la manera de acceder a ellas es mediante aritmética de [punteros](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puntero_(inform%C3%A1tica)). Esto es que teniendo un puntero a un elemento, puedes sumar un valor N a dicho puntero para acceder al elemento N-ésimo a partir de dicho puntero (o restar N para acceder al N-ésimo elemento previo); por este motivo puedes expresar una formación de tamaño arbitrario con un simple puntero.

#### Tu clase pila.

Vemos que tiene tres miembros:

```
tElemento *elementos;              //Vector de elementos
int Lmax;                          //Tamaño del vector
int tope_;                         //Posicion del tope
```

Seguramente espera implementar la pila mediante una formación de tamaño fijo (almacenado en `Lmax`) y recordar hasta que posición se tienen almacenados elementos usando la variable `tope_`; es un tipo de implementación que puede ser más eficiente que la implementación mediante Nodos siempre y cuando se tenga una formación (vector de elementos) inicial suficientemente grande... pero si se supera dicha capacidad inicial se deberá pedir memoria de nuevo y re-alojar los elementos anteriores, lo cuál suele ser muy costoso.

---

1. También conocidas como arreglo o en inglés arrays.